# Word file Viewer in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, viewer

I am using Karma commercial template. I have make the plugin for to upload document or any type of file, which will save in database and give option of Preview in front end. I have search many plugins for the same. I don't want to download the file but only wanted to preview the file in read only mode.Please help for the same.

Comment: I have used iframe and embed for the same but it doesn't worked

Comment: I need "Document viewer"

Answer (score 0):

I have used javascript code using javascrip plugin:

var documentViewer = $('#document-preview').documentViewer();

But it is not usefull for word file as it is useful for image, pdf and text file.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Document Embedder plugin allows you to display files (PDF, Word, etc.) and has options that will prevent downloads.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-document-embedder/